# Nuget Moq 4.0.10827 and InternalsVisibleTo (Again)

Tags: c#-4.0, moq, nuget

I have been trying to get Moq (or rather Castle.Core) to create proxies for my internal types.

The following (when added to my project under test), allows things to work:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

However this (more secure version) does not:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, PublicKey=002400000480000094000000060200000024000052534131000400000100010077f5e87030dadccce6902c6adab7a987bd69cb5819991531f560785eacfc89b6fcddf6bb2a00743a7194e454c0273447fc6eec36474ba8e5a3823147d214298e4f9a631b1afee1a51ffeae4672d498f14b000e3d321453cdd8ac064de7e1cf4d222b7e81f54d4fd46725370d702a05b48738cc29d09228f1aa722ae1a9ca02fb")]
```

Note: the public key here differs to that [documented here](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart), I re-checked the public key of the Castle.Core.dll that ships with the current Nuget version of Moq.

Do I still have the wrong key?

[EDIT]

I have noticed the full Moq download from the official site (rather than Nuget) contains a NET40-RequiresCastle folder with a smaller dll, which implies that the Castle.Core code has been included in the default Moq.dll I guess.

I was looking at the Castle.Core.dll they provide for Silverlight and assuming they'd have used the same version throughout?

Comment: Did you try the documented one?

Comment: Yep, tried the documented one, doesn't work (for Moq 3 only I think).

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old, but for anyone who stumbles across this, I was having a versioning issue with Pex and Moq at one point, and wound up finding the most direct and useful approach to be the [Strong Name Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  That is, I found opened a Visual Studio command prompt and used "sn -Tp ThirdPartyAssembly.dll" to query it for the key directly.  This proved a lot more efficient than perusing the internet looking for different, documented public keys to try out.

Comment: .NET 4 version link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks -- didn't check the version that came up for the google search.  :)