# Mocking Methods within a Concrete Class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class that conducts a series of business logic processes that work on a model, one of which is:

```
public virtual void TryToRunProcess(Model model)
{
    var result = RunCheckMethodOne(model) && RunCheckMethodTwo(model);
    if (result)
        RunMethodThree(model);
}

internal virtual bool RunCheckMethodOne(Model model)
{
    ...
}

internal virtual bool RunCheckMethodTwo(Model model)
{
    ...
}

internal virtual void RunMethodThree(Model model)
{
    ...
}
```

Assuming that the model and its associated RunCheckMethodOne() and RunCheckMethodTwo() methods are sufficiently complex to warrant their own set of unit tests, I want to test that the appropriate responses from RunCheckMethodOne() and RunCheckMethodTwo() result in the correct execution of RunMethodThree().

I'd like to do this by mocking the business logic class, and setting up the two check methods to return specific results, and then verifying that the third method is executed.

One of my unit tests is:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TryToRunProcessBothCheckMethodsAreTrueShouldExecuteMethodThreeTest()
{
    var model = new Model();

    var mock = new Mock<ModelBusinessLogic>();
    mock.Setup(r => r.RunCheckMethodOne(It.IsAny<Model>())).Returns(true);
    mock.Setup(r => r.RunCheckMethodTwo(It.IsAny<Model>())).Returns(true);
    mock.Setup(r => r.RunMethodThree(It.IsAny<Model>())).Verifiable();

    mock.Object.TryToRunProcess(model);

    mock.Verify(r => r.RunMethodThree(It.IsAny<Model>()), Times.Once());
}
```

Now, to me this looks like it should work, however when I run this unit test the RunCheckMethodOne() and RunCheckMethodTwo() methods are not being mocked as I'd expect; they actually execute within the ModelBusinessLogic class, rather than returning the value set up in the mock.

What should I be doing in my implementation to ensure that I can keep all the business logic methods in the same class (so as not to create an over-engineered solution) and still being able to mock methods within the business logic class to exercise specific scenarios in other methods?

I am using .Net Framework 4.5 and Moq 4.0.0.0.

Comment: Does mock.Callbase = true help?

Comment: I tried using that flag as well and that doesn't seem to help. According to the intellisense help for Moq the CallBase property defaults to the base virtual implementation when there is no Setup present. That doesn't look like it will help me as I already have Setups in place that I want to use explicitly rather than the underlying implementation in ModelBusinessLogic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things:

- mock.CallBase = true;
- Make the internal methods public or protected internal instead (obviously less than ideal).

I also think you should consider breaking up your class if, as you say, there is sufficient complexity to warrant individual testing. It doesn't sound like it would be over-engineering to me.

EDIT

You can alternatively add

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

to your class if it isn't strong-named. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188603/nuget-moq-4-0-10827-and-internalsvisibleto-again) for more.

Comment: Or protected internal.

Comment: Thanks James!  Adding the protected internal keywords to the method signatures for RunCheckMethodOne(), RunCheckMethodTwo(), and RunMethodThree() seems to do the trick.  I didn't need to set mock.CallBase = true to get the behaviour that I was looking for.  My next question (purely for academic peace of mind) is why protected internal methods behave differently to internal methods in this case?

Comment: "protected internal" means  the member is both protected and internal - it has both qualities but not the "intersection" of both. Adding protected makes the member accessible in derived types, even if created in another assembly.

Comment: Added the `InternalsVisibleTo` alternative